# Java letter guessing program

Tags: java

I'm trying to make this simple game. But I have no idea what's wrong with this code. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class letterguess {
    private static String[] animals = {"snake","dog","cat","bird","whale","ant","wolf","bear","mouse","rabbit","elephant","dragonfly","kangaroo","tiger","komodo","koala","chicken","lion","horse","goat","cow","gorilla","camel","chipmunk","octopus","lobster","phanter","frog","zebra","lizard","baboon","deer","bison","hamster","hyena","shark"}; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] true_answer = {"Right", "Awesome", "Cool"};
        String [] false_answer = {"Wrong answer!", "Oops!"};
        String [] word;
        String [] show_word;

        Random string = new Random();

        int i, n=0, start, random=0, z=0, word_size, size;
        char tryagain=0;
        boolean output=true, main=true, error=true;

        System.out.print ("Press 1 to start, 2 to exit: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        start = input.nextInt();

        if (start==1){
            main=true;
        }
        else{
            System.exit(0);
        }

        while(main){
            random = string.nextInt(animals.length);       
            word = animals[random].split("");                             
            show_word = animals[random].split("");                    

            for(word_size=0;word_size<animals[random].length();word_size++){
                n=word_size;
            }                                           

            for(i=1;i<animals[random].length();i++){    
                show_word[i] = "_";
            }

            if(n==3){     
                for(i=0;i<1;i++){
                    size = (int) (Math.random()*n);
                    show_word[size]=word[size+1];
                }
            }   
            else if(n==4){
                for(i=0;i<2;i++){
                    size = (int) (Math.random()*n);
                    show_word[size]=word[size+1];          
                }
            }
            else if(n==5){
                for(i=0;i<2;i++){
                    size = (int) (Math.random()*n);
                    show_word[size]=word[size+1];
                }
            }
            else if(n==6){
                for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                    size = (int) (Math.random()*n);
                    show_word[size]=word[size+1];
                }
            }
            else if(n>=7){
                for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                    size = (int) (Math.random()*n);
                    show_word[size]=word[size+1];
                }
            }

            do{ 
                for(i=0;i<animals[random].length();i++){
                    System.out.print(show_word[i]);      
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
                System.out.print("\t 1");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
                System.out.print(" 2");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
                System.out.print(" 3");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
                System.out.print(" 4");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
                System.out.print(" 5 ");

                System.out.print("\n Answer: ");
                Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);         
                String word3 = input2.nextLine();          


                if(word3.equals(animals[random])){ 
                    int True = (int) (Math.random()*2+1);
                    System.out.println(" ==> " +true_answer[True]);
                    output=false;
                }
                else{
                    int False = (int) (Math.random()*2+1);
                    System.out.println(" ==> "+false_answer[False]+"\n");
                    output=false;
                }
            }while(output);

            System.out.print("\n Try Again (Y/N) : ");
            Scanner input3= new Scanner (System.in);
            tryagain = input3.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
            if(tryagain=='y') 
                main=true; 
            else if(tryagain=='n')  
                main = false;

            else
                while(error){
                    System.out.print ("\n Wrong Input. Please input Y or N: ");
                    Scanner input4= new Scanner (System.in);
                    String next=input4.nextLine();
                    if(next.equals("Y")||next.equals("y"))
                        break;
                    else if(next.equals("N")||next.equals("n")){
                        error=false;
                        main=false;
                    }
                    else
                        continue;     
                }

        }  
        System.out.print ("\t\t\t(\tGAME OVER\t)");    

    }
}
```

The problem is, the output is not something I expected. 
I expect something like **ho_s_** for **horse** or **_l_ph___** for **elephant** but it shows something like **or_e_** for **horse** and **ee___nt_** for **elephant**.

Can someone fix this for me? I've tried anything that I know and still can't fix it. I'm sorry before and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it was nice to be able to run everything, in the future, you should consider focusing on the problem-part of your code, which is the display for spacing, which is only 3 lines long and much easier to debug.

```
        for(i=1;i<animals[random].length();i++){    //<-- 
            show_word[i] = "_";
        }
```

This for-loop is the problem. `i` should start at 0.

```
        for(i=0;i<animals[random].length();i++){    //<-- 
            show_word[i] = "_";
        }
```

Modified output:

```
horse
___s_    1 2 3 4 5 
 Answer: horse
```

*Edit*

Here's the bug with the sizing issue:

```
        for (word_size = 0; word_size < animals[random].length(); word_size++) {
            n = word_size;
        }
```

You're attempting to set n = to word size, but the logic you've provided is inaccurate. You're actually getting `word_size - 1`

So with 3 letter words, you get 2, which means no letter is replaced.

You could replace all this with:

```
n = animals[random].length(); //returns 3 for cat
```

Comment: As an aside to this, there may be a bug with 3-letter words. `___` is really hard to guess.

Comment: Yes, also found that bug and I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: and I have fixed i to 0 but it still starts with the second letter

Comment: @crzylazy I am not able to replicate that issue with the code you've provided. Everything is working properly once that change is made for me. However, I've updated my answer to address your 3-letter word issue.

Comment: @crzylazy I think I found your issue. `show_word[size]=word[size+1];` should be `show_word[size]=word[size];`

Comment: Thank you very much. Works well now. I still have a question, how to make the hints easier, I mean __r__ for horse is hard to guess. How to make it shows more letter for long words?

Comment: @crzylazy you could probably ask that in a new question, but it involves your `if-statements` for selectively making the letters available.